# Extract a word from string which is based on another string in C# with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

Maybe the question could be confused, I'm very n00b to Regex, I'm trying my best, but no success.

I have the following ***text***:

```
  public const int A_KEY  =               789;
  public const int A_KEY1 =               123;
  public const int A_KEY2 =               555;
```

Above string contains spaces and white spaces.

I want to get that number (789 or 123 or 555) based on a key text (A_KEY, or A_KEY1, or A_KEY2)

If I provide A_KEY I want to get 789, and so on.

I tried something like:

```
string code = "A_KEY";
string pattern = @"[public const int " + code + @"] (\s) [=] \s (\d+)";
Regex reg = new Regex( pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
Console.WriteLine( pattern );
Match m = reg.Match( text );
if ( m.Success ) {
    Console.WriteLine( m.Groups[2] );
}
```

Where is my mistake in my regex ?

Comment: I don't see any regex in your code..

Comment: Could you please post the regular expression you are using?

Comment: Without the value for `pattern`, which we presume you used to initialize `reg`, we won't be able to tell.

Comment: @ChristmasUnicorn: Post updated, sorry for this missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following pattern:

```
string pattern = @"public const int (?<Key>[\w\d_]+)\s+=\s+(?<Value>[\d]+)";
```

then you will have two named groups (`Key` and `Value`) for each match. You can use LINQ to find one, for example `A_KEY`:

```
var match = Regex.Matches(input, pattern)
                 .Cast<Match>()
                 .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Groups["Key"].Value == "A_KEY");
if (match != null)
{
    var value = match.Groups["Value"].Value;
}
```